# How can we give Dynamic path for install App

Tags: appium, nunit, teamcity, perforce, appium-ios

Project : IOS app
Lang : C#
FW : NUnit Framework
AT : Appium

According to our framework, we are automating ios app using simulator, but we provided .app file path as hardcoded, nee to give Dynamic path, our project is in Perforce both ios build and test trigger will be in teamcity pipeline.

I tried to give relative path by ../../../../, but it wont work

Comment: "Dynamic" can mean many things to many people. :-)

Comment: "Won't work" how?  Who/what exactly did you give that relative path to and what was its notion of the current working directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Appium server argument either `--app` in case of simulator or `--ipa` in case of real device
Syntax to use this

```
--ipa <path to ipa file>
```